# Training text corpus too big to load into memory

Tags: python, keras, out-of-memory, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have created a 2-stacked LSTM model that I want to train on a recent dump of English Wikipedia articles (15.1 GB of text). I am not able to load the corpus into a text variable for making the word embedding. How are Keras RNN models generally trained on such huge text corpora to as to avoid memory errors?

After trying to open 15.1 GB file with:

```
text = open('/home/connor/Desktop/wiki_en.txt').read().lower()
```

**I get this error message:**

> (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>   MemoryError

Comment: Or have a look at other ways to provide data to your network (for example, generators or `tf.Dataset`s if you use Tensorflow's backend)

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with same problem for my Deep Learning project. I can suggest 2 options:

1. **EDIT:** You should consider batching your data  <del>by converting them into small binary pieces with some serializer libraries (This [blog](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/python-serialize/) can help for choosing a library)</del>. Since you are dealing with text data you can split the data into small meaningful pieces (e.g assuming the data contains different types of news, it can be spited as politics, sports, health etc as different text files - batches). Then you can read created text files batch-by-batch and fit your model for training. Since I do not know anything about your text data, just trying to light the way! I have just deleted the binary case because it was a wrong solution approach.
2. Keras has its own `fit_generator` method, check it from [here](https://keras.io/models/sequential/). The method, simply, takes an argument which is a function that generates batches and trains the models with generated batches. This allows using CPU for generating batches while GPU is handling training process in parallel

By the way, I used the second one which is a way faster ;)
I hope it helps.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You actually answered your question yourself. **File is to big to fit into RAM memory.**

Instead of trying to read everything into memory at once try processing it line by line for example. e.g.

```
with open('....') as wiki_en: 
   for line in wiki_en: 
       line.lower()
       #do some more processing
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to overcome the built-in memory limit with the tds library, which lets you build more-or-less equivalent structures that aren't limited by memory cap. This won't help with the limits of your hardware, but you will be able to have things like tables that are bigger than 2 GB.

https://github.com/torch/tds

Comment: No. It won't help. The problem is not a hardware or software limitation but the wrong approach to usage of data. You simply can't load such a huge file (15.1GB or more) into memory at once. What if the file size would be 15.1 PB?